# UISearchBar triggered functions

Tags: ios, events, swift, triggers, uisearchbar

My entire app interface is made programatically from **ViewController.swift**

Inside the view is `UISearchBar`. What are the names of functions which I can **override** in order to run my own code when `UISearchBar` is tapped on, when the keyboard's Search button is pressed and when `UISearchBar's` Cancel button is pressed?

If they don't exist, can I trigger my own functions at those times?

Comment: Command click on UISearchBarDelegate that should be added to your class and you will see the protocol functions.

Comment: This should all be documented in the Apple Docs https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISearchBarDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UISearchBarDelegate https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISearchBar_Class/index.html

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to add conformance to the [`UISearchBarDelegate` protocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISearchBarDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UISearchBarDelegate/searchBarSearchButtonClicked:) to your view controller:

```
extension ViewController : UISearchBarDelegate {
    func searchBarTextDidBeginEditing(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        // ...
    }

    func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

and then set the search bar's delegate to `self`.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the `UISearchBarDelegate` you can implement the following methods...

```
 //Becomes first responder
 - (BOOL)searchBarShouldBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar;
 //Editing begins
 - (void)searchBarTextDidBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar;
 //Cancel button pressed
 - (void)searchBarCancelButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar;
```